# AWS Lambda Data getting Cached

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using python structlog for logging data in a Lambda application.
The logger object is getting initialised in each lambda invocation but I am still seeing lambda caching issues.

When a new invocation happens for lambda, few data in the logs are getting populated correctly and with recent data but few are getting populated from old data.

Can someone please help me understand why caching is happening in lambda.

Example :

```
{
"level": "error",
"account_number": "80691000151",
"email": "mini************",
"message": "[lambda_handler](account-number: 80691034243) Exception:Connection Aborted}",
"epoch_timestamp": 1638253641.8506558,
"timestamp": "2021-11-30T06:27:21.850657Z"
}
```

here we can see the account number logged and the account number in the message is different, the account number in message is from a previous invocation.

Comment: Show the code of your Lambda function. If you're initializing logger outside of the handler function, this can happen, due to reusing of the context

Comment: Without fully understanding the context of the code you're trying to run, my guess is that you've got some shared code within the Lambda execution context.  AWS Lambda allows you to 'share' data between executions if it's placed outside of the Lambda handler function.  Note that how long this data is shared for is indeterminate as it's subject to the Lambda instance being de-allocated at any time in order to provide capacity in AWS, however, as a rule-of-thumb, the larger the size of the Lambda, the longer it is before it's returned to the 'pool'.

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: any update on this ? I am facing similar issue, I dynamically send code to lambda to execute, and it seems like it just caches the result of the code execution (function call) and return the result of previously sent code on new invocation